# Error when using CefSharp WinForms

Tags: c#, vb.net, cefsharp

I'm currently using CefSharp in order to embed an Asp.Net website inside a Windows Form. When running on Visual Studio everything works fine, but when I build the application and then I deploy it to the client (User Pc) I get an error that says "Could not load file or assembly 'CefSharp.Core.dll' or one of its dependencies". The main application is built in x86, thus we're using CefSharp in x86. I've updated the .Net Framework, I even copied icutdtl.dat but nothing gets solved. Currently it only works in one client but in the in the others it doesn't.

What could be the problem that causes CefSharp to fail?

Comment: the problem could be one of 2 things ..look at the properties page when you click on that reference in the designer and see if the `CopyToLocal` property is set = to `true` or make sure that the dll is on that target machine what is the operating system of the target machine(s) change x86 to anyCPU as well this sounds like a reference issue

Answer (score 0):

`CefSharp` uses `VC++ 2012` for which you need to install the `redist` on the client machines or include the relevant files in your bin directory. Make sure you install the matching version, either `x86` or `x64`.

You can download the `redist` from https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2977003

Also see this `FAQ` entry should you wish to include the libs as part of your app.
https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Frequently-asked-questions#6-how-do-i-include-the-visual-studio-c-2012-redistributables-on-the-target-app